# Some parts of curves are being cut off by the frame in my multiple curve plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot several curves and show them in the same figure, but parts of curves being cut off by the frame and not showing fully.

I am using the commands `Plot` and `Show`

```
P24 = Plot[Evaluate[FT /. sol7], {t, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "FT(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P25 = Plot[Evaluate[Fz /. sol7], {t, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "Fz(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P26 = Plot[Evaluate[FT /. sol8], {t, -20, 20}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "FT(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P27 = Plot[Evaluate[Fz /. sol8], {t, -20, 20}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "Fz(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P28 = Plot[Evaluate[FT /. sol9], {t, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "FT(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P29 = Plot[Evaluate[Fz /. sol9], {t, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "Fz(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P30 = Plot[Evaluate[FT /. sol10], {t, -20, 20}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "FT(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Pink, Thick}, PlotRange -> Full]
P31 = Plot[Evaluate[Fz /. sol10], {t, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "Fz(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Pink, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P32 = Plot[Evaluate[FT /. sol11], {t, -20, 20},
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "FT(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P33 = Plot[Evaluate[Fz /. sol11], {t, -20, 20}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "Fz(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P34 = Plot[Evaluate[FT /. sol12], {t, -20, 20}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "FT(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
P35 = Plot[Evaluate[Fz /. sol12], {t, -20, 20}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t(s)", "Fz(pN)"}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]

p38 = Show[P24, P26, P28, P30, P32, P34]
p39 = Show[P25, P27, P29, P31, P33, P35]
```

In the plots made with `Show`, parts of curves are missing, especially from the top of the figure. Look to the red and black curves.

[image]

Also, I want the scale of the *x*-axsis to be `-20 , -15, -10, -5,0, 5, 10, 15, 20`. I tried to use `Ticks`, but it didn't work.

```
Ticks -> {{-20, -15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15, 20}, {-0.2, -0.1, 0.1}}
```

Also, if there is any way to make the curves clearer, please tell me

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

This is more Mathematica-ish, and doing it this way you won't be risking to get those scaling problems:

```
sols = Table[ {FT -> i Sin@x, Fz -> i Cos@x}, {i, 7, 12}];
(* in your case
   sols = {sol7, .... sol12};
   but I bet you already had them as a single list at an earlier stage in your program and
   you decided to assign a different symbol to each one
*)
cols = {Orange, Black, Yellow, Pink, Red, Green};
Plot[Evaluate[Transpose[{FT, Fz} /. sols]], {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> cols]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks alot,but my system is more complex so I did not know how to use     slos

Comment: @Yaya "Slos"? I guess you mean "sols". It doesn't matter. Just do `sols = {sol7, sol8, ..., sol12}` and then use my last two lines.

Comment: yes sorry I mean sols ,I added my system above , the thing that change is \[CapitalOmega]c

Comment: thanks alot it is work now,do you know any way to change the scale of axsis?